# Why am I Gettting all NAN while Appending a new Field to a Data Frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, group-by

This is very strange to me.  I have a data frame with a field that has file names, like this.

```
df['file']
```

The file names look like this.

```
0     FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCB02 03312011.txt
1     FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCB02 03312011.txt
2     FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCB02 03312011.txt
3     FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCB02 03312011.txt
4     FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCB02 03312011.txt
5     FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCB02 03312011.txt
```

How can I parse out the last string between the last two spaces, so it looks like this.

```
RCB02
```

I am trying to append that to a data frame, like this.

```
grouped_and_summed['schedule_code'] = df['file'].str[24:27]
```

When I look at the data frame, I have all NAN.

[image]

What I want is to have the `grouped_and_summed` data frame have `RCB02`, displayed correctly, and show as the very first column in the data frame.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Series.str.extract` method with some simple regular expressions and then set the new column to the `.values` of the result set:

```
df.loc[:, "schedule_code"] = df["file"].str.extract(r"FFIEC CDR Call Schedule (\w+) \d+\.txt").values
```

Output -

```
                                         file schedule_code
0  FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCB02 03312011.txt         RCB02
1  FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCB02 03312011.txt         RCB02
2  FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCB02 03312011.txt         RCB02
3  FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCB02 03312011.txt         RCB02
4  FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCB02 03312011.txt         RCB02
5  FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCB02 03312011.txt         RCB02
```

### Validation

It does keep things aligned. Here's another dataframe where the last RCB value is different:

```
                                         file
0  FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCB02 03312011.txt
1  FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCB02 03312011.txt
2  FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCB02 03312011.txt
3  FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCB02 03312011.txt
4  FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCB02 03312011.txt
5  FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCB03 03312011.txt # I'm different!
```

And the output is:

```
                                         file schedule_code
0  FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCB02 03312011.txt         RCB02
1  FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCB02 03312011.txt         RCB02
2  FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCB02 03312011.txt         RCB02
3  FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCB02 03312011.txt         RCB02
4  FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCB02 03312011.txt         RCB02
5  FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCB03 03312011.txt         RCB03 # Still here!
```

Comment: That looks like the way to go!!  However, when I try to append it to my data frame, like this:

    grouped_and_summed.loc[:, "schedule_code"] = df["file"].str.extract(r"FFIEC CDR Call Schedule (\w+) \d+\.txt").values

I get this error message:

ValueError: cannot set using a multi-index selection indexer with a different length than the value

Also, this:

grouped_and_summed["schedule_code"] = df["file"].str.extract(r"FFIEC CDR Call Schedule (\w+) \d+\.txt").values

Gives me this error: 

ValueError: Length of values (24) does not match length of index (96)

Comment: Hmm...those errors make sense.  It looks like your grouped_and_summed has an index like `"RCONG306", "RCONG307", ...`, so the index values won't match up.  What would be an example `"schedule_code"` value for index `RCONG306`?  Are there any other matching fields (columns) in `df`?

Comment: If I go back a few steps to the original df, in the filed named 'file', I have this 'FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCB02 03312011.txt'.  If I try to run your code, as such: 

df["file"].str.extract(r"FFIEC CDR Call Schedule (\w+) \d+\.txt").values()

I get this error message: 

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Comment: The index on the original df is the same as this:

df["file"].str.extract(r"FFIEC CDR Call Schedule (\w+) \d+\.txt").values()

Right.  I think it should be.  I'm confused now.  Your code works fine in your example, but not in my actual data set.

Comment: Yep, `.values` doesn't need parenthesis.  You could try skipping values and create a separate Series object, then merge the two on the axis.  If you run `df1 = df["file"].str.extract(r"FFIEC CDR Call Schedule (\w+) \d+\.txt")` then `df.merge(df1, left_index=True, right_index=True).rename(columns={0: "schedule_code"})`, it will add the results onto `df` based on the index of each pandas object.

Comment: Without seeing a sample of all of `df`, I'm just going by what you're saying.  You can also try just `.loc` on the expression: `df["schedule_code"] = df.loc[:, "file"].str.extract(r"FFIEC CDR Call Schedule (\w+) \d+\.txt")`.  That worked for me.